# Android wrapper library around gomobile generated AAR library

Tags: android, gradle, aar, gomobile

I want to make an Android library where most of the code is written in Go using [Gomobile](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gomobile#hdr-Build_a_library_for_Android_and_iOS) .
Gomobile produces an `.aar` library when I run `gomobile bind ...`.

I want to make a new library in Kotlin that internally uses the generated Gomobile library.
The problem is that when I build my library and try to use it in an app, it crashes with the following error as soon as one of the generated Go functions are called.

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI GetObjectRefType called with pending exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lmobile/ProtocolOptions
```

When comparing the contents of the AAR archives of my library with the Gomobile generated one, I can see that the `jni` directory is not copied over to my library.

I can make it work by also importing the Gomobile generated library in my application, but I would like to have them combined in a single library.

---

The configuration for my library is as follows.

```
- settings.gradle.kts
- library/
  - build.gradle.kts
  - src/...
- golibrary/
  - build.gradle.kts
  - gomobile-library.aar
```

`settings.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "Library"
include(":library")
include(":golibrary")
```

Library module `build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    // Omitted...
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")

    // INCLUDE GO GENERATED LIBRARY
    implementation(project(mapOf("path" to ":golibrary")))
}
```

Gomobile library module `build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
configurations.maybeCreate("default")
artifacts.add("default", file("gomobile-library.aar"))
```